# Magento dropdownattribute with existing products for webshopowner to fill out

Tags: php, mysql, magento, webshop

Manage Options

Hello,

I was wondering if it's possible for magento to display the current products in a dropdown menu for the shopowner to select as an attribute value.

For instance I've made a customattribute called engine for a product(car) and I want him to be able to select wich engine the car has from the engines he already put into the system.

ADMIN: Catalog → Attributes → Manage Attributes → New Attribute

Then make a dropdown menu, then to be able to select existing products as a value for the attribute.

Hopefully this is clear enough.

Comment: thats what configurable and bundled product types are for

Answer (score 0):

If you made the attribute a select or multi select field then you can manage the options from the tab on the left when editing the attribute. If it was a text field then no, not with out custom programming.